# how to prevent as.POSIXct from simplifying times

Tags: r

I have a character that I would like to make class `POISXct`

This works as expected:

```
x = "2018-06-29 06:00:00"
as.POSIXct(x) ## "2018-06-29 06:00:00 EDT"
```

However if the hours should be `00:00:00` it is dropping everything but the date:

```
as.POSIXct(x) - hours(6) ##  "2018-06-29 EDT"
```

What do I have to change so that

```
as.POSIXct(x) - hours(6)
```

returns

```
"2018-06-29 00:00:00 EDT"
```

Comment: You misunderstand _internal representation_ (always at full precision) and _default display format_ (where it was decided to drop redundant information).  But setting an _explicit_ format you can get what you have.  This question has likely dozens of duplicates here.

Comment: `format(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` thanks.

Comment: Yup. I am not sure you can override the system default for `format.POSIXt` so besides a helper function you could sub-class.  But that smells like overkill.